Sampling Correlated Poissons conditional on their sum
I want take samples of size $n$ from a joint distribution $(X,Y)$ such that the marginal $X$ and $Y$ distributions are both Poisson and their sums are constrained to some values $\sum_n x_i = S_x$ and $\sum_n y_i = S_y$.
In the univariate case the Poisson distribution conditioned on the sum is just a mulitnomial distribution which is easy to sample from.
In the bivariate case we can define a joint Poisson distribution by defining
$$
X = X' + Z \quad \text{and} \quad Y = Y' + Z
$$
and $X'$,$Y'$ and $Z$ are all Poisson distributed and $Z$ to controls the strength of the correlation. I tried following the same method as the univarate case but was unable to derive the joint distribution conditioned on the sums. The best I have come up with is a simple rejection approach but of course this becomes unfeasible when I want to generate large samples.
Any advice how to proceed or if this is possible would be appreciated.

So after thinking about this for a bit I have come up with a solution. My approach is re-frame the question in terms of the three independent variables that make up the bivarate Poisson $X'$,$Y'$ and $R$ where
$$
X = X' + R\\
Y = Y' + R
$$
First we make use of the fact that the distribution of a sample of $n$ Poisson variables conditional on their sum $S = \sum_i^n x_i$ is simply a multinomial with $S$ trials and $n$ events
$$
 (x'_i,...,x'_n) \sim \text{Multinomial}(S, n)
$$
This means that the vectors of $X'$,$Y'$ and $R$ all follow a multinomial distribution varying only in thier sum $S_{x'}$,$S_{y'}$ and $S_r$.
Now we need to work out what these sums should be to get the desired total sum and covariance. To do so we simply write out the constraint on their values imposed by the desired sums of $X$ and $Y$
$$
    S_x = S_{x'} + S_r \\
    S_y = S_{y'} + S_r 
$$
Then, we sample the values of $S_r$ to get the desired covariance. As $S_r$ is the sum of $n$ Poisson variables it is distributed as
$$
S_r \sim \text{Pois}(n\lambda_r)
$$
where $\lambda_r$ is the desired covariance. From this we get the values of $S_{x'}$ and $S_{y'}$. From here we can just sample $X'$,$Y'$ and $R$ from their multinational distributions and then sum them to get the samples of $(X,Y)$
